# $C[0,1]$ is not compact under maximum norm

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

The question could be duplicate. But I just want to know if my argument has any flaw in it.

Let $X = C[0,1]$ and $d(f,g) := \max_{x \in X} |f(x)-g(x)|$. Suppose if X was indeed compact, then it is also totally bounded. That is, $\exists \;\epsilon > 0$ such that $X$ can be written as $\bigcup_{i=1}^N B_{\epsilon}(x_i)$. Then $d(f,g)\; \leq N \cdot (2\epsilon)$. But $\forall\;\epsilon > 0$, I can find a constant function continuous in [0,1] such that $f(x) = 2N\epsilon + 1$ $\forall x \in X$. Thus, $X$ cannot be totally bounded and hence, not compact.

> Theorem: *Metric Space X is compact iff X is complete and totally bounded*

I am doubtful because such seemingly straight forward proof is not seen anywhere. So I am confused.

Comment: You are correct. The (a little bit) harder question is whether the closed unit ball in $X$ is compact.

Comment: Thank you. Okay I'll try that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your proof seems correct but note that you can also use the much easier fact that a compact metric space must be bounded and $C([0,1])$ is not bounded. In fact, any non-zero-dimensional normed space $(X,||\cdot||)$ cannot be bounded because if $v \in X$ with $||v|| \neq 0$ then

$$ d_X(0,\lambda v) = ||\lambda v|| = |\lambda| ||v|| $$

for $\lambda \in \mathbb{F}$ is arbitrary large.